# How are coroutines implemented in smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, coroutine

Can I implement coroutines in smalltalk?

If your answer is no: why not?

Or if its yes: can you give me an example?

Comment: Cab you give more explanation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most Smalltalk have stack manipulation methods on the thisContext object. You could use these to implement coroutines though dealing with the stack at this level may prove a bit tedious.

GNU Smalltalk and recent versions of Squeak and Pharo also offer a Generator class that makes it easy to write generators (i.e. types of coroutine that yield multiple values):

```
"This generator yield an infinite sequence of 1"
generator := Generator on: [ :gen | [ gen yield: 1 ] repeat ].

(1 to: 100) do: [:i | Transcript show: (generator next printString); cr]
```

Comment: Do you know if implementation of Generators is also available for Pharo 1.3?

Comment: Generators have made their way into Pharo 1.4. Adding Pharo to the answer.